# C++: get value of memory address from a text file

Tags: c++

I have a text file with a single line that stores the memory address to a variable (of type double) being used in the code.

Content of temp.txt:  `0x7f3c00844c00`

I would like to read this line and dereference it to get the double value stored at the address (i.e. 0x7f3c00844c00)

This is what I tried:

```
std::fstream temp;
temp.open("temp.txt");
string address;
getline(temp, address);
temp.close();
std::cout << *strtoul(address, NULL, 16) << std::endl;
```

That does not work --> "cannot convert std::string to const char *"

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: "_I have a text file with a single line that stores the memory address to a variable (of type double) being used in the code._": How? Did you write it to the file beforehand during the same program execution? What is the point?

Comment: Yup, each time the code runs it re-writes the text file to ensure the memory address is valid for the value of the double variable. I am trying to learn how to use hexadecimals string directly rather that using the "&" memory reference. For example, instead of typing std::cout << *a << std::endl where a is memory pointer, I would like to do std::cout << *0x877EE << std::endl;

Comment: Are you familiar with the parameters that [`std::stroul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) expects?  Do you agree that the error message is describing a real problem in your code?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @NoRainDropsInTheSky Sorry, but I don't understand what "_I am trying to learn how to use hexadecimals string directly rather that using the "&" memory reference._" means and is there any reason to write this to a file and read it back instead of simply using the value directly? Is this just pointless trying out? If so, `std::istream` has a `operator>>` overload that can read a `void*` directly. Then you only need to cast back to the correct pointer type to get the `double*`.

Comment: Years ago someone I was conversing with used this an argument against garbage collectors. What if you write a pointer into a file, and then lose the last in-memory pointer to the object? The object is still reachable through the file, but the garbage collector doesn't know that. :)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `std::stream temp; temp.open("temp.txt"):` to `std::stream temp("temp.txt");`. Second, you don't need to call `temp.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `strtoul()` is wrong for 3 reasons:

- it takes a C-style null-terminated `const char*` string as input, not a `std::string` object. Hence the compiler error you are seeing. Use the `std::string::c_str()` method, or the `std::stoul()` function, to solve this.
- it returns an integer, not a pointer. Use)reinterpret_cast` to solve this.
- the integer value it returns may or may not fit in a pointer, depending on which platform this code is running on. So, you are risking truncating the resulting pointer. Use `std::strtoull()` when running on a 64-bit system.

Try this instead:

```
std::ifstream ifs("temp.txt");
std::string str;
std::getline(ifs, str);
temp.close();
uintptr_t address = std::strtoul(str.c_str(), NULL, 16); // or std::strtoull()
double *pdbl = reinterpret_cast<double*>(address);
std::cout << *pdbl << std::endl;
```

That being said, consider using `operator>>` instead, as it has an overload for reading in a pointer, eg:

```
std::ifstream ifs("temp.txt");
void* address;
ifs >> address;
ifs.close();
double *pdbl = static_cast<double*>(address);
std::cout << *pdbl << std::endl;
```

Comment: @user17732522 OK, I removed it